# Error when do Graphical unit tests for a Kivy app

Tags: kivy

I want to try the Graphical unit tests as the official [documents](https://kivy.org/docs/contribute-unittest.html) said:

I have `nose` and `coverage` installed. 
But after I typed `make test` 
I get an error: 
`make: *** No rule to make target 'test'.  Stop.`

How to fix this, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *make* command should be run from the root folder of the **kivy** source folder.

basically it only does:

```
test:
    -rm -rf kivy/tests/build
    $(NOSETESTS) kivy/tests
```

You can also just use this command **without going through the Makefile**:

```
python -m nose.core your_project/your_tests
```

About the render function (r), I'll copy some part of the docs here:

```
Each call to self.render (or r in our example) will generate an image named as follows:

<classname>_<funcname>-<r-call-count>.png
r-call-count represents the number of times that self.render is called inside the test function.

The reference images are named:

ref_<classname>_<funcname>-<r-call-count>.png
You can easily replace the reference image with a new one if you wish.
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer, seems work, but still end up with 'Ran 0 tests in 0.000s', any idea? I used your 'python -m nose.core my_test.py' approach. The code inside is from the kivy official graphic test document. I think the confuse part is there is no assert, just r(), what does this render function assert here?

Comment: It seems you don't have any tests in the file ... anyway the **r** (*render*) will create an image file, you can save those file and use them later for comparison

Comment: Thanks, a little bit confused here, what happened after calling that r()? Just render a picture? Do we need to check whether it is right or wrong by our eyes? I followed the official docs, it seems they only called r()...I expect some sort of comparison method here.

Comment: Thanks, I saw that in the kivy documents as well. But how to make the assertion from the image file name? How to compare the images via code?Anyway, I think it should be a new question. You answer does work for my question.